# how to set multiple labels over this KUNDLI image in swift 4 and XCODE 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How it look like in iPhone 6 Plus
[image]

How it look like in iPhone X

[image]

i want to display text over the image for every screen sizes without disturbing the text on image.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please open the links to see the images.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes sir please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this is not a code writing service. Your question should include a precise problem, what you have tried to resolve it and where you need help.For further information, please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i just set the label on image in storyboard with autolayout constraints.

Comment: use fixed width and height constraints for your image view which can be set in all screen size and then set labels constraints accordingly.

Comment: do you want to set the labels on the image or outside the image?

Comment: on the image  as i have shown an image above.

Comment: Ok so you can wrap the labels into a stack view and then give the constraints on the image accordingly

Comment: could you please explain little bit?

Comment: @himanshusoni Refer to this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2 You will understand it in a better way.

Comment: Saurabh i think stack view will not solve this problem, i tried out what the instructor instructed in an article. any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

easy solution

add fixed width and height to the image and place constraints to the label from the image center

complex solution

you may need to use laers and draw the UI instead of using an image.

Comment: i am gonna follow this and lets see if it works. by the way thanks to reply.